# problem with key press event

Tags: jquery, html

i have an application in which i have table with 3X4 cells i move among table cell using arrow keys(up,right,left,down).focus is set to initial cell(cell00) and from there keyevents are defined. i have zoomin/zoomout module that zoomin when button inside cell gets focus and zooms out on blur. if i use tab key both zoomin/zoomout works fine. if i use arrow keys it just zooms the image but zoomout will not be called. any idea why is it happening so.

here is my [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/rashmi/gacgv/1/)

some one please help on this issue

hey i have updated my demo have look you will get better idea.[demoupdated](http://www.jsfiddle.net/rashmi/AH3fA/)

Comment: can any one help me solve this issue. i am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this before the "switch"?

```
//...
cell = $(this).parent('td');
if(e.keyCode != 9){ //9 is the tab key
  cell.find('button').blur();
}
switch(e.keyCode)
//...
```

And for your zoom out. I think it's just that you are zooming out too fast, it's firing but you are doing it for 0ms, I changed it to 500ms like your zoom in does:

```
$('button:has(img)').blur(
    function(){
        $(this).find('img').animate(
            {
                'width': '57px',
                'height': '120px'
            }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: hey thanks for your help. i could solve one issue with your help. but still zoomout is not working in both cases 1) when i use arrow keys to move among images in table 2) using tab key to move among image. i hope i am clear.

Comment: hey mr. chan please suggest me something on this issue.

Comment: no Mr. Chan i have changed that value in my updated demo. even then my zoomout is not working. images gets zoomin but not zoomout. you can have look in to my "demoupdated". please do suggest me something on how to solve this issue. as i am totally stuck with this issue since 15 days. hope you help me out to solve this issue.